# Difference of elements to find same adjacent

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

I just started learning Pythonby myself last night. I have accomplished a few simple things like getting a file from a user, opening and reading that file into a list line by line, calculating the number of integers per line, calculating the number of unique integers per line using set, and calculating the number that appears the most per line.

An additional interesting concept that I am looking into and would like to accomplish is calculating the number of integers based on the number of adjacent integers. That might sound a bit confusing so I will explain below:

Say I have a list with the values:

```
['1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '4', '4', '4', '4', '5', '5', '6', '7', '7', '7', '1', '1\n']
```

(I believe I would have to convert the strings to int?)
The first integer is a 1 and the second integer is a 2. The difference is not 0 is the two integers are not the same so do not increment a counter. Take the next integer which is a 2 and the previous integer which is a 2. The difference is 0 so the two integers are the same so increment a counter. And so on. The final value would be 8 in this case.

I looked in adjacent integer calculations on SO and the Internet, and only found subtraction algorithms which I thought could apply.

Here is what I have so far without currently complicating with converting the strings to int (which I have a question on after pertaining to this, please):

```
x = [1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,6,7,7,7,1,1]
count = 0
xdiff = [x[n]-x[n-1] for n in range(1,len(x))]
print xdiff
all([xdiff[0] == xdiff[n] for n in range(1,len(xdiff))])
for n in range(1,len(xdiff)):
    last = x[n-1]
if xdiff!=0:
      print "Different numbers"
      print last
      if xdiff==0:
        print "Same numbers"
        count+=1
```

Here is the output:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, -6, 0]
Different numbers
7
```

The first to prints are just for testing, but the last print should be 9 when the calculations are correct.

Any suggestions of how to improve my algorithm to calculate the total number of integers in a list excluding the same adjacent integers (like I demonstrated above for clarification)? Also, since I just started teaching myself Python, any suggestions on general improvement for my code is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

UPDATE:
So I realized that my calculation value is incorrect and the total number should be 8 and not 9. Here is a better explanation:
I have the following numbers in a list:
[1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,6,7,7,7,1,1]
There are 20 elements total.
The number of adjacent integers is 8.
Start at 1 and look at 2. 1 and 2 are not the same so increment. Look at next value of 2 and previous value of 2. 2 and 2 are the same. Look at the next value of 2 and the previous value of 2. 2 and 2 are the same. Look at the next value of 2 and the previous value of 2. 2 and 2 are the same. Look at the next value of 2 and the previous value of 2. 2 and 2 are the same. Look at the next value of 3 and the previous value of 2. 3 and 2 are not the same so increment. And so on.

Now all of the answers are one less than the correct answer, so is that due to the starting at data[0] and I just need to add one to my total?

UPDATE:
Output:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '5', '4', '5\n']
bursts: 0

['14', '62', '48', '14\n']
bursts: 0

['1', '3', '5', '7', '9\n']
bursts: 0

['123', '456', '789', '1234', '5678\n']
bursts: 0

['34', '34', '34', '34', '34\n']
bursts: 4


['1\n']
bursts: 0

['1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '4', '4', '4', '4', '5', '5', '6', '7', '7', '7', '1', '1\n']
bursts: 12
```

Code:

```
#Open the file corresponding to the name of the file
#the user entered. Open and read the file.
with open(filename, 'r') as file:

    #Read the file in line by line
    for line in file:

        #Remove all empty lines and lines that start with a # sign
        if line.strip() and not line.startswith("#"):

            #Calculate the number of integers per line
            names_list.append(line)
            #print "integers:", len(line.split())

            print names_list
            #Calculate the number of bursts
            result = sum(int(names_list[i]) == int(names_list[i+1]) for i in range(len(names_list)-1))
            print "bursts:", result
```

Output should be:

```
bursts:9
bursts:4
bursts:5
bursts:5
bursts:1
bursts:1
bursts:8
```

Comment: I don't understand why it should be 9.

Comment: @StefanPochmann You are correct..it should be 8, but none of the calculations from below are correct (one less). I will update with greater explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a working code:

```
numbers = [1,3,7,11,25,36,57,678,999]
count = sum([numbers[i] == numbers[i+1] for i in range(len(numbers)-1)])
>>> count
8
```

For your example:

```
data = [1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,6,7,7,7,1,1]
result = sum([data[i] == data[i+1] for i in range(len(data)-1)])
>>> result
7
```

Comment: I performed other test cases and the value of result must be incremented by 1 because the list starts at position 0. Thank you!

Comment: Now, I accepted your answer because it was the most helpful to me. However, I did say that I had another question which was how to use convert strings to int in the list for that..any suggestions, please sir/madam?

Comment: @Justin_Finland, sure, you could use `int([data[i]) == int(data[i+1])` to cast your `str` to `int`, but make sure that you have valid data, because it raises an error, when you'll have not `int` value in your string

Comment: Unsupported operand types for -: list and int with: `result = sum(int([names_list[i]] == int(names_list[i+1]) for i in range(len(int(names_list-1)))))`

Comment: please double check your code: replace: `int([names_list[i]]` with `int([names_list[i])`

Comment: Parenthese is considered invalid syntax like this: `result = sum(int([names_list[i]) == int(names_list[i+1]) for i in range(len(int(names_list-1))))`

Comment: @Justin_Finland, You're inattentive :) It works: `result = sum(int(names_list[i]) == int(names_list[i+1]) for i in range(len(names_list)-1))`

Comment: Wow...thank you. For some reason, the result values are now incorrect.

Comment: @Justin_Finland, could you share more realistic data? I'll double check it

Comment: @Justin_Finland, so, where it returns invalid result? you want the solution which tells that `34` and `34\n` are different values? it looks like your parsing solution is not so good. To skip `\n` in the end of the line, you could write: `string.strip()` to your code, when you're parsing some string data and inserting it to your list

Comment: Please take a look at the desired output that I updated with. All of the values are incorrect. Before I added additional complexity to the problem, your solution worked perfectly. However, now I have this: `['1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '4', '4', '4', '4', '5', '5', '6', '7', '7', '7', '1', '1\n']` which needs the operation to be performed on. Can you please elaborate more on the string.strip()? Any suggestions, please.

Comment: @Justin_Finland, so, for this case it returns `12`. What do you expect?

Comment: The value of 8 because 1 is 1, 22222 is 2, 33 is 3, 4444 is 4, 55 is 5, 6 is 6, 777 is 7 and 11 is 8.

Comment: @Justin_Finland, could you try this one: `result = sum([int(names_list[i]) != int(names_list[i+1]) for i in range(len(names_list)-1)]) + 1`?

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help! That solved it. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Justin_Finland, np, but try with more tests, because in the beginning I was thinking that the main idea is a little different :)

Comment: Yes, it is correct because I tried with 6 other cases. Awesome and thank you again. (:

Answer (score 2):

The nice thing about python is using what you already get for free. Like [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> numbers = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, -6, 0]
>>> pairs = zip(numbers, numbers[1:])
>>> sum(x == y for x, y in pairs)
7
```

This generates all pairs by zipping these two lists:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, -6, 0] # numbers
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, -6, 0] # numbers[1:]
# generates: [(1, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0),
#             (0, 1), (1, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0),
#             (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0), (0, 0), (0, -6), (-6, 0)]
```

Then, it checks which are the same (It also uses the fact that `True` counts as `1`, so a simple `sum` works).

Keeping indices and handling edge cases can usually be avoided.

Comment: Nice use of iterables!

Answer (score 1):

More simply, use a counter that increments by 1 each time and checks whether adjacent values are equal:

```
l1 = ['1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '4', '4', '4', '4', '5', '5', '6', '7', '7', '7', '1', '1\n']

nums = [int(num) for num in l1]

sum(nums[i] == nums[i+1] for i in range(len(nums)-1))
Out[157]: 12
```